# Grab a section from a large file between two known substrings using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a pretty large XML file without line-breaks.

It's so big it's slow to open and operate on in Emacs or other text editor. But I just want to extract a shortish section of it between two known substrings.

I don't care about preserving the XML structure, I just want a chunk of characters.

This ought to be a one-liner in sed, no?

Any idea how to do this? I tried adapting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words but it doesn't seem to work when I pipe my file into it. (It works on toy examples, but I'm thinking that my file may be too big.)

Comment: Do you hvae access to GNU sed and/or GNU grep?

Comment: I assume so, I'm in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

With `frompattern` and `topattern` in output:

```
grep -o 'frompattern.*topattern' file.xml
```

Without `frompattern` and `topattern` in output:

```
grep -Po 'frompattern\K.*(?=topattern)' file.xml
```

Comment: It says `grep: Not a recognized flag: P` `grep: Not a recognized flag: o` in my shell. Can you help me out with some other code ? @Cyrus

Comment: @learner1: Try this with GNU sed or non GNU sed: `sed 's/.*frompattern\(.*\)topattern.*/\1/ file.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually it's easy to do with sed.
But it's ALWAYS easy to do it with awk:

```
awk '/frompattern/,/topattern/' your.xml > chunk.xml
```

Here the two patterns are regular expressions (as would be with sed).
If it discourages you for any reason, you can use simple strings, if you know where they are:

```
awk '$x=="fromstring",$y=="tostring"' your.xml > chunk.xml
```

Here x and y are the field positions of the strings you want to be the barrier signs. (More can be done with tiny effort.)

Comment: No. These don't seem to work. The first gives me the whole document back. (Remember there are no linebreaks so the document is on a single line). And the second doesn't seem to produce any output at all.

Comment: Ah, ok, no linebreaks. So we must set the record separator (both for  input and output) to a more reasonable thing than linebreak and that would be ">" here:  awk -vRS='>' -vORS='>' '/frompattern/,/topattern/' your.xml > chunk.xml   As for the strict string version, yes since it's hard to aim the Nth field when theres no real lines, it makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

I use a command called `pv` (Pipe viewer) - once installed you can see the progress of the command and how long to complete. great for large files

For Mac - (for others go to [ostechnix.com](https://ostechnix.com/monitor-progress-data-pipe-using-pv-command/#:%7E:text=In%20such%20cases%2C%20you%20can,by%20giving%20the%20following%20information%3A&text=total%20data%20transferred%2C,and%20ETA.))

```
brew install pv
```

my example is using sed.

```
pv bigFile.txt | sed -n '/^FIRST PART OF STRING/,/^LAST PART OF STRING `/p' > output.txt
```

If you dont use `pv` you can just use anything else to echo the file

eg. `cat` or `echo`